# Stop thread anyhow android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have several activities going one by one with a button click, but if button isnt clicked during 10 seconds next activity starts automatically with the help of thread.

```
button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab1.this, Tab2.class);
startActivity(firstIntent);                 
            finish();
        }
    }); 

Thread background = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

     try {

     sleep(10*1000);


     Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Tab2.class);
     i.putExtra("CountNum", count);
     startActivity(i);

     finish();

     } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    background.start();
```

The problem is: if I go from tab1 to tab2 and then to tab3 with a button click, then in 10 seconds tab2 will start again because of thread from tab1, which was still running(I did not know it works this way =\ ). How to fix it? How to stop the thread if I used a button? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use a thread, use a Timer or a CountDownTimer. There are lots of examples here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a time that `.stop()` has been deprecated an highly discouraged as it might terminate your `Thread` in an unsafe way.

The most common approach is having a `boolean` controller inside your `Thread`, which will check if some action happened (in your case, a button has been pressed), and if so, in the next loop iteration, simply use `return` within your `Thread`. This will terminate it cleanly and safely.

**---- EDIT ----**

Suppose this is your button `onClickListener()`:

```
boolean has_been_clicked = false;

but = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);

but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Do the stuff your need
    has_been_clicked = true;
  }
}); 

new Thread(
  new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
      while (!has_been_clicked) {
        // Do your stuff here...

        ...
      }
      // If you've reached this point, it means you have clicked
      // the button since the value of has_been_clicked is true,
      // start your Activity here
      ...
      startActivity(i);
      return;
    }
  }
).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example i hope it will help i just modify you code a bit .

First create a Boolean OKToStart , it will be use to check if we are within 10sec laps

```
button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
boolean OKToStart =true;
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(OKToStart){
Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab1.this, Tab2.class);
startActivity(firstIntent);                 
            finish();
 }
        }
    }); 

Thread background = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    while(OKToStart){

     try {

     sleep(10*1000);


     OKToStart =false



     } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }};

    background.start();
```